# Matplotlib in spyder, on/off interactive plot for a single file only

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have the following question. Is there a way to change to `'qt'` setting without changing this setting for the spyder as a whole.

I have multiple programs that I use for plotting in different styles. And I would like only the 3D plot program to use the interactive windows. But when I do that and then I run a 2D plot program it uses the interactive window instead of giving it `'inline'` .

I use this lines in the 3D plot program:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
windows_mode = ['inline', 'qt'][0]
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', windows_mode)
```